# How to Access `/dev` From Inside a `chroot` Jail?

Tags: macos, nfs, chroot, dev, chroot-jail

How can one access `/dev` from within a `chroot` jail?  I'd like to know how to do this on OS X v10.11.5 'El Capitan,' in particular.  I've already tried to create an `automount`ing NFS share in order to emulate a bind mount to do this (as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1082980/unbound-dns-setting-up-an-nfs-share-to-bring-dev-into-the-softwares-chroot)) without success.  **Are there any other options?**

Comment: If you can't bind mount into the chroot, then you will have to make a `dev` directory in the chroot with the device files you need.  You can copy them with `cp` - IIRC it has an option you can use to copy a special file directly and not access its underlying device - or use `mknod`.

Answer (score 2):

MacOS has a special filesystem called devfs which can be mounted in multiple places. Just mount it inside your chroot jail, like so:

```
sudo mount -t devfs devfs "$jail"/dev
```

Comment: This method seems not specific to macOS. It works on [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails-build.html) too, at least.

Comment: Just thought I'd come back to note that devfs only seems to be available when you build your XNU kernel from source with the right options, IIRC…

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the idea of a chroot jail in the first place:)

Copying the /dev-files into a dev-directory inside the jail will most likely not work. As LawrenceC suggested, using mknod from within the jail might do the job.

Comment: so, instead of binding /dev into chroot we could create a /dev path there and put there only the specific devices we want? Also, I wonder if this could also be done with /proc?